# C# Fody.PropertyChanged The "Fody.WeavingTask" task could not be initialized

Tags: c#, fody, fody-propertychanged

I was using the Fody and Fody.PropertyChanged NuGet packages successfully in my solution until I was installing another package and saw there we're updates available to those previously mentioned packages.  After updating, the following errors are preventing me from building my solution.

> The "Fody.WeavingTask" task could not be initialized with its input
>   parameters.
>
> The "GenerateXsd" parameter is not supported by the "Fody.WeavingTask"
>   task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable
>   public instance property.

I went and checked the GitHub page for Fody, wondering if there was something new I had to add to FodyWeavers.xml or something...that file is still the same as it was before I updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>
```

Why did simply updating these packages break my app?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem with these steps, hope this helps someone else in the future:

1. Uninstall Fody.PropertyChanged, then Fody packages.  Close Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to the projects folder
3. Open yourprojectnamehere.csproj in a text editor.
4. Search for any lines containing "Fody" and remove them, save the file, reload Visual studio and install Fody and Fody.PropertyChanged again.